# Array with first images of multiple folder and array of all images from specific folder

Tags: php

I would like to echo all image1 from multiple folders, folders have random name and only contains images.

```
folder1->
     image1
     image2
     image3
folder2->
     image1
     image2
     image3
folder3->
     image1
     image2
     image3
```

echo would be something like.

```
echo "<img src=".$image1." alt=' '>";
```

Further I like to have the image as an link, but clicking that link will echo all images of the folder
If echo is image1 of folder1, when clicked, I have an array of all images of folder1..like this??

How to convert this to code? I have no idea!

```
echo "<a href=".$all_images."><img src=".$image1." alt=' '></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
for($i = 0; $i<count(folderArray); $i++){
    echo '<a href="'.folderArray[$i][0].'">';
    for($j = 0; $j<count(folderArray[$i]); $j++){
        echo '<img src="'.$folderArray[$i][$j].'">';
    }
    echo '</a>';
}
```

Where folder-array is your whole Array. This will make the A link the link to the first image in the folder, which is good if you want a thumbnail or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dir = "/images/";

// Sort in ascending order - this is default
$a = scandir($dir);

// Sort in descending order
$b = scandir($dir,1);

print_r($a);
print_r($b);
?>
```

above code display all files form directory. try and develop